# Soap Log in using 5 parameters android

Tags: java, android

In my application, I want to contact the web service and return a boolean value if the result is successful. I parse 5 fields for security reason but i don't know how to send and receive input and output using soap. I followed a w3school example, it works fine with one inputs, but now i am getting confused with several data. Help please, here's my code.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapObject loginTo = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "LoginDetail");

PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
loginTo.addAttribute("idCon", "124059432");
loginTo.addProperty("codeSession", "1234");
loginTo.addProperty("type","CLIENT");
loginTo.addProperty("client_number","167");
loginTo.addProperty("account_num","3403");
loginTo.addProperty("codeAuth","333");

request.addProperty("loginDetails", loginTo);

Log.e("Soap Request : ", "" + request);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

    Log.e ("login result", response.toString()); //lblResult.setText(results.toString());

    Boolean loginStatus = Boolean.getBoolean(response.getProperty("success").toString());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Why did you use two SoapObject?

Comment: i saw an example am new to it so i am trying examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


request.addProperty("codeSession", "1234");
request.addProperty("type","CLIENT");
request.addProperty("client_number","167");
request.addProperty("account_num","3403");
request.addProperty("codeAuth","333");

Log.e("Soap Request : ", "" + request);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try

{
    aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

    Log.e ("login result", response.toString()); //lblResult.setText(results.toString());

    Boolean loginStatus = Boolean.getBoolean(response.getProperty("success").toString());

}
```

use like this. hope it will work.

Comment: getting SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:...

Comment: please post your full code i need NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME,SOAP_ACTION,URL.

Comment: hi can we chat private please ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26992/discussion-between-nirmal-and-yakusha)